# Substring: From a Certain Position to End

Tags: r, string

I have this list ("sample_list");

```
[1] "http://www.website.ca/extra/city1-aaa-bbb-ccc/"    
[2] "http://www.website.ca/extra/acity2-a2a-bbb-ccc/"   
[3] "http://www.website.ca/extra/bbcity3-a3a-bbb-ccc/"   
[4] "http://www.website.ca/extra/ccccity4-a77a-bbb-ccc/"   
[5] "http://www.website.ca/extra/dddddcity5-a2a-bbb-ccc/"
```

I want to extract the following parts from this list: `city1, acity2, bbcity3, ccccity4, dddddcity5`

I had the following idea about this. I noticed that for all elements in this list, the first position is always the same position  `"http://www.website.ca/extra/` (29th position).

```
my_substr = substr(sample_list, 1,29)
```

- Is there someway I can modify the sustring function so that everything is selected from the 29th position all the way to the first hyphen?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
x = c("http://www.website.ca/extra/city1-aaa-bbb-ccc/", "http://www.website.ca/extra/acity2-aaa-bbb-ccc/", 
"http://www.website.ca/extra/bbcity3-aaa-bbb-ccc/", "http://www.website.ca/extra/ccccity4-aaa-bbb-ccc/", 
"http://www.website.ca/extra/dddddcity5-aaa-bbb-ccc/")
```

*From the 29th position all the way to the first hyphen?*
Yes,

```
substring(x, 29, stringr::str_locate(x, "-")[,1] - 1)
```

although other options exist for such task. Depending on preference, this might be more suitable.

```
stringr::str_extract(x, "(?<=extra/).*(?=-aaa-)")
```

Comment: @ Donald Seinen: I made some changes - is there a way to adapt your code? thank you so much!

Comment: @antonoyaro8 it seems you have copied console output (judging from the [1], [2], ...). It looks like a vector, as lists would have double brackets when printed in the console. if it is indeed a list, i recommend unlisting it, then use the function, then use as.list. Alternatively, use lapply, but not recommended since substring is vectorized

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `str_extract` from stringr package

```r
library(stringr)

strings <- c(
    "http://www.website.ca/extra/city1-aaa-bbb-ccc/",
    "http://www.website.ca/extra/acity2-aaa-bbb-ccc/",
    "http://www.website.ca/extra/bbcity3-aaa-bbb-ccc/",
    "http://www.website.ca/extra/ccccity4-aaa-bbb-ccc/",
    "http://www.website.ca/extra/dddddcity5-aaa-bbb-ccc/"
)

str_extract(strings, "(?<=extra\\/)\\w+(?=-aaa-)")
#> [1] "city1"      "acity2"     "bbcity3"    "ccccity4"   "dddddcity5"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>